# Why won't this code break the while True loop in python?

Tags: python

Just started learning python earlier today and I can't work out why this code won't end the program if "N" is entered. Also if I change the last if statement to != "Y" then even if I type Y then it closes which is confusing me so much. I was just trying to make a simple program to convert Fahrenheit to Celcius if prompted without looking up any of the code so if it's badly written that's why.

```
while True:
    def temp_func():
        print("Is the temperature you'd like to convert in Fahrenheit or Celcius?")
        temp = input()
        if temp == "Fahrenheit":
            F_temp = int(input("Please write the temperature."))
            converted_temp_F = ((F_temp - 32) * 5 / 9)
            print(str(converted_temp_F))
        elif temp == "Celcius":
            C_temp = int(input("Please write the temperature."))
            converted_temp_C = ((C_temp * (9 / 5)) + 32)
            print(str(converted_temp_C))

    temp_func()
    print(input("Would you like to convert another temperature? (Y/N) "))
    if input == 'Y':
        True
    if input == 'N':
        break
print ("Goodbye")
```

Comment: `input` is a function. It's not a string. When you call `input("Would you like...")` it returns a string and that's what you should be comparing to Y or N.

Answer (score 1):

replace your print(input...  and conditions with:

```
 response = input("Would you like to convert another temperature? (Y/N) ").upper()
 if response == 'N':
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the input value given by the user in a variable for `Y/N`. You should move the function out of the `while` loop

```
def temp_func():
    print("Is the temperature you'd like to convert in Fahrenheit or Celcius?")
    temp = input()
    if temp == "Fahrenheit":
        F_temp = int(input("Please write the temperature."))
        converted_temp_F = ((F_temp - 32) * 5 / 9)
        print(str(converted_temp_F))
    elif temp == "Celcius":
        C_temp = int(input("Please write the temperature."))
        converted_temp_C = ((C_temp * (9 / 5)) + 32)
        print(str(converted_temp_C))

while True:
    temp_func()
    Y_N = input("Would you like to convert another temperature? (Y/N) ")
    if Y_N == 'N':
        break
print ("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
def temp_func():
    print("Is the temperature you'd like to convert in Fahrenheit or Celcius?")
    temp = input()
    if temp == "Fahrenheit":
        F_temp = int(input("Please write the temperature."))
        converted_temp_F = ((F_temp - 32) * 5 / 9)
        print(str(converted_temp_F))
    elif temp == "Celcius":
        C_temp = int(input("Please write the temperature."))
        converted_temp_C = ((C_temp * (9 / 5)) + 32)
        print(str(converted_temp_C))

while True:

    temp_func()
    x = input("Would you like to convert another temperature? (Y/N) ")
    if x.lower() == "n":
        break
    
print ("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```py
print(input("Would you like to convert another temperature? (Y/N) "))
```

Here, if you do -

```
input("Would you like to convert another temperature? (Y/N) ")
```

It will do the printing for you, and take an input. now what you need to do is store the value in a variable. For example:

```
choice = input("Would you like to convert another temperature? (Y/N) ")
```

Now compare the `choice` variable and you are good to go!